# How to choose the previous or next image in a directory?

Tags: java, image, directory, jfilechooser

So I have made a simple image viewer program, with a JFileChooser, wherein I load an image into the icon of a label. I also save the directory location. I have two buttons in my main application, previous and next, how would I make it so that when I press them, they load either the previous image or the next one from the same directory? I guess it would be some form of regular expression search plus or minus an integer but I'm not sure how this would look, I'm not so bright on regular expressions.

I should probably add that I have a method, draw(BufferedImage image) which takes a BufferedImage sent to it and draws it on the JLabel, and a method loadImage(File file) which loads any image sent to it. So I load the file and then draw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dir.listFiles( aFileFilter )` to list all files in the directory. Write yourself a FileFilter (an anonymous one is fine) which only matches files of the required type (those whose extension is .jpg, .png, .bmp, .gif).

An example:

```
File[] images = dir.listFiles( new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept( File pathname ) {
        String name = pathname.getName();
        return name.endsWith( ".png" ) || name.endsWith( ".jpg" );
    }
} );
```

Once you have that array of files you can find the position of the current file with a linear search, and then select the next or previous one easily.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I want, could you give me an example of a FileFilter? I'm not sure what one would look like.

Answer (score 1):

> I also save the directory location

Then you can use File.listFiles(...) to get an Array of all the files in the directory. You would probably want to filter this to only get image files.

Then you would want to sort this Array by filename.

When you want the next/previous image you can search though the Array to find the index of the currently visible image and then add/subtract 1 to get the next image to display.

Edit:

See: [Filtering the List of Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters)

Comment: That's basically exactly what I wrote, only 35 seconds earlier. Good answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Got it working with the two suggestions here.